# Finding all tablets of a database in YugabyteDB snapshots

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Looking at the docs in https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/manage/backup-restore/snapshot-ysql/, for a database , how would I easily query all the tables(UUID) related to that database without having to look through the management UI (core version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `yb-admin list_tables` https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/admin/yb-admin/#list-tables
You’ll get an output like the following:

```
/yb-admin -master_addresses <master-ip-address:port>,<master-ip-address:port>,<master-ip-address:port> list_tablets ysql.northwind employee_territories 0
```

```
Tablet-UUID                             Range                                                           Leader-IP               Leader-UUID
2a2fd4c64c9c40518a0f185e236b6669        partition_key_start: "" partition_key_end: "\007\377"           ---------------------------------:9100  4e28b6addae349f0a05222b3f90ccc55
5990513fc6404b78bdcbf71205de1e89        partition_key_start: "\007\377" partition_key_end: "\017\376"   ---------------------------------:9100  4e28b6addae349f0a05222b3f90ccc55
….
```

And then you can check the Leader-IP to find on which node the leader-tablet data reside. You can also check or use this script: https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/blob/master/managed/devops/bin/yb_backup.py